# How to have two entry fields that update each other after each keystroke

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to Python and I am trying to do this excercise as homework.
It's a Km to Miles and viceversa converter.

The UI has two entry fields: one for Km and one for Miles.

Each time an entry field is updated after a key stroke, immediately the other field should be updated with the calculated value. Much like the google converter works.

[image]

I am using StringVar().trace for each of the entry fields. (I am not sure if it could be done with one only).

I am having two problems:

1. When typing in the Km entry field for example, I have the Miles entry field delete the value first and then insert the new one. Between each update there is a moment when the value is "" (nothing), and then I get the error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''.
2. Both fields are setup to update each other after a change. When I update the value in Km, the value gets converted to Miles right away. And the other way around. But, the problem is that they get stuck updating each other after I change one for the first time. I hope I am making sense.
   How do I stop Km from being updated by Miles when I am typing in Km?

Let me know if you need more information.

Here is what I have:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

IMAGE_PATH = "./images/road.gif"
KM_TO_MILES = 0.621371
MILES_TO_KM = 1.60934

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Km <-> Miles")
window_x_size = 300
window_y_size = 300
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
window_x_position = (screen_width / 2) - (window_x_size / 2)
window_y_position = (screen_height / 2) - (window_y_size / 2)
root.resizable(False, False)
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (window_x_size, window_y_size, window_x_position, window_y_position))

top_frame = tk.Frame(master=root, width=400, height=100, bg="red")
top_frame.pack()

root_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(IMAGE_PATH))
root_image_label = tk.Label(top_frame, image=root_image)
root_image_label.pack()

bottom_frame = tk.Frame(master=root)
bottom_frame.pack(fill="none", expand=True)

entry_var_km = tk.StringVar()
entry_var_miles = tk.StringVar()


def on_entry_change_km(*args):
    km_value = float(entry_var_km.get())
    print("New value :", km_value)
    entry_miles.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry_miles.insert(0, str(round(km_value * KM_TO_MILES, 2)))


def on_entry_change_miles(*args)
    miles_value = float(entry_var_miles.get())
    print("New value :", miles_value)
    entry_km.delete(0, tk.END)
    entry_km.insert(0, str(round(miles_value * MILES_TO_KM, 2)))


entry_var_km.trace("w", on_entry_change_km)
entry_km = tk.Entry(master=bottom_frame, textvariable=entry_var_km, width=10, font='Arial 24', justify="right")
entry_km.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

label_to_from = tk.Label(master=bottom_frame, text="TO / FROM", pady=10)
label_to_from.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

entry_var_miles.trace("w", on_entry_change_miles)
entry_miles = tk.Entry(master=bottom_frame, textvariable=entry_var_miles, width=10, font='Arial 24', justify="right")
entry_miles.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tracing two tkinter variables which update each other may cause recursion issue.  Suggest to bind on `<KeyRelease>` event on the entry widget instead.  Also you need to cater exception on converting empty string to float number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this help:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

IMAGE_PATH = "./images/road.gif"
KM_TO_MILES = 0.621371
MILES_TO_KM = 1.60934

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Km <-> Miles")
window_x_size = 300
window_y_size = 300
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
window_x_position = (screen_width / 2) - (window_x_size / 2)
window_y_position = (screen_height / 2) - (window_y_size / 2)
root.resizable(False, False)
root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (window_x_size, window_y_size, window_x_position, window_y_position))

top_frame = tk.Frame(master=root, width=400, height=100, bg="red")
top_frame.pack()

root_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(IMAGE_PATH))
root_image_label = tk.Label(top_frame, image=root_image)
root_image_label.pack()

bottom_frame = tk.Frame(master=root)
bottom_frame.pack(fill="none", expand=True)

entry_var_km = tk.StringVar()
entry_var_miles = tk.StringVar()

# Add Boolean variables to track updates
km_var_updated_programmatically = False
miles_var_updated_programmatically = False

def on_entry_change_km(*args):
    global km_var_updated_programmatically
    if not km_var_updated_programmatically:
        km = entry_var_km.get()
        try:
            km_value = float(km)
            print("New value (Km):", km_value)
            entry_var_miles.set(str(round(km_value * KM_TO_MILES, 2)))
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            entry_var_miles.set("")

def on_entry_change_miles(*args):
    global miles_var_updated_programmatically
    if not miles_var_updated_programmatically:
        miles = entry_var_miles.get()
        try:
            miles_value = float(miles)
            print("New value (Miles):", miles_value)
            entry_var_km.set(str(round(miles_value * MILES_TO_KM, 2)))
        except (ValueError, TypeError):
            entry_var_km.set("")

entry_var_km.trace("w", on_entry_change_km)
entry_km = tk.Entry(master=bottom_frame, textvariable=entry_var_km, width=10, font='Arial 24', justify="right")
entry_km.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

label_to_from = tk.Label(master=bottom_frame, text="TO / FROM", pady=10)
label_to_from.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

entry_var_miles.trace("w", on_entry_change_miles)
entry_miles = tk.Entry(master=bottom_frame, textvariable=entry_var_miles, width=10, font='Arial 24', justify="right")
entry_miles.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mohamad! It works perfectly and I actually understand why! :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer for the first question:
I suggest to add a boundary value judgment ,do special treatment handling of empty values

The answer for the second question:
I suggest you to convert you code logic from sequence structure to the parallel structure,parallel the Km to Miles and Miles to Km,let the one modification will only execute the one of the two logics once